# Unable to remove a folder containing file

Tags: robotframework

I'm using Robotframework 3.0 in java platform using RIDE on windows 10. I'm trying to use commands from the Operating system library like `"Empty Directory and Remove Directory"`. After executing those commands I get this error: `"OSError: unlink(): an unknown error occurred: Directorypath"`   and `Directory does not exist`

Here is the list with all the combinations I used and the output I received

[image: List of commands used on RF]

My questions are:
1. Using Remove Directory recursive=True; Why this command is not able to delete the folder if it has a file. I was able to use the same command without any errors.
2. Using Empty directory, Why I'm getting error that the directory does not exist. I understand that the directory is not available. I was assuming that this command will ignore if the directory is not available. If my assumption is wrong then how can I solve it. 
I would need help on the fail scenarios.

Comment: What help do you need?  The error you've shared seems to be suggesting the path doesn't exist?

Comment: Just updated the question. Please let me know if you still have any doubts. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Empty Directory` does in fact check does the target directory exist (that happens in a private keyword `_list_dir` in the library).

If you want to call it, and not fail the case if the dir does not exist, then surround it in `Run Keyword And Ignore Error`:

```
${rc}  ${msg}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Empty Directory  ${target dir}
Run Keyword If   '${rc}' == 'FAIL'     Handle Failed Deletion As You Like
```

As for 1), when you do call `Remove Directory` with `recursive=True`, it will/should have no problems deleting the directory and any files/subdirectories from it.
The error you're seeing - `OSError: unlink() ...` is propagated by the python's shutil module, which does the actual deletion. There could be a number of reasons - the account you're running the tests with does not have permissions to delete that specific file (most likely), the file was added in parallel with the delete operation (not that likely, the exception would then be that the holding dir could not be unlinked), or similar reasons. Try it with a different path, not the windows user's temp dir, but one on which content you're sure you have full access and control.